# Number of rings with additive group $(\mathbb{Z}_{16})^2$. A341547(16) in OEIS

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, computer-algebra, associative-algebras

I would like to know if somewhere the number of non-isomorphic rings with additive group $(\mathbb{Z}_{16})^2$ is mentioned. If not, is someone able to calculate it?

And (easier) the commutative case? A341548(16) in OEIS.

Comment: For other cases we have information at https://web.archive.org/web/20061002201537/http://www.algebra.uni-linz.ac.at/~noebsi/ringtable.html

Comment: What do you mean by a ring? Is it associative with identity? Or not necessarily associative? Or not necessarily with identity?

Comment: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)

Comment: @BugsBunny associative

Comment: not necessarily with identity

Comment: Cannot you use the same method as in https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.01623v1 for counting the algebras? I feel that it should sail through with additional calculations.

Comment: @BugsBunny I think there are more than 1000, it can only be done in a computational way.

Comment: They have done infinitely many without a computer. They form 5 families...

Comment: Their argument works for curled algebras over $Z_{16}$ without much fuss. Now suppose it is straight. Then we have a basis $x,y$ such that $x^2= ay$. Then $xy=yx=bx+cy$ and $y^2$ is uniquely determined. Thus, a straight algebra is determined by by 3 elements of $Z_{16}$: all solutions are easy to write. You may need a PC to determine which of them are isomorphic.

Comment: Should I write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

It is not an answer but rather a method, outlined in https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.01623v1 . We adapt it to the ring $Z_{16}$.

We say an algebra is curled if every element $x$ of order 16 is linearly dependent with $x^2$. An algebra is straight otherwise.

If the algebra is curled, it has a basis $x,y$ such that $x^2=kx$ and $y^2=ly$. WLOG, $k,l\in\{0,1,2,4,8\}$. Writing $xy=ax+by$ and $yx=cx+dy$, we get a collection of 6 elements satisfying equations (3), (4) and (5) from the paper. Any collection will give an algebra. The number of collections is $5^2\cdot 16^4 = 1638400$. Such search is within computer possibilities but I suspect that it can be narrowed down much further.

If the algebra is straight, it has a basis $x,y$ such that $x^2=ky$. Again, we can restrict to $k\in\{1,2,4,8\}$. I would choose the smallest such $k$ possible among all the bases. If $k=1$, then $xy=yx=bx+cy$ and $y^2$ is determined. In this case, a straight algebra is commutative and is determined by 2 elements: $16^2 = 258$ possibilities. The analysis in the paper goes through.

The cases of higher $k$ require considerations, not covered in the paper. I suspect they are not difficult with $k$ being the smallest possible quite helpful: write $xy$ and $yx$, making sure that no $x+ay$ yields a smaller $k$.

To determine the isomorphism types, I would the criterion on page 4 and computer. The group $GL_2(Z_{16})$ has 4 generators and $6\cdot 16^3=393216$ elements. One can apply the generators to the $2\times 2$-matrices determining algebras: this gives all the orbits. There is probably a simpler method of just looking for

Comment: I have to reflect on it. Can you tell me how many of them are commutative?

Comment: I don't really know how rewards work. In this case the answer is not entirely satisfactory.